# Polarion Variant 'Pure Variants server cannot be found'

Tags: variant, polarion

When trying to generate a document from a Variant 'Generate Documents' button, the job keeps failing with the 'Pure Variants server cannot be found' error.

has anyone seen this before?

Log:
'''

```
2022-11-10 13:27:09,078 [ajp-nio-8889-exec-11 | u:julien.llanes] INFO  root  - Job "Generate Variant Documents" has id 61b91006-0a780dcc-70337f2a-746e4b7f
2022-11-10 13:27:09,078 [ajp-nio-8889-exec-11 | u:julien.llanes] INFO  root  - State of job "Generate Variant Documents" changed to UNSCHEDULED
2022-11-10 13:27:09,093 [ajp-nio-8889-exec-11 | u:julien.llanes] INFO  root  - Working directory of root job "Generate Variant Documents" is D:\Polarion\data\workspace\polarion-data\jobs\20221110-1327
2022-11-10 13:27:09,093 [ajp-nio-8889-exec-11 | u:julien.llanes] INFO  root  - Job "Generate Variant Documents" runs as user "julien.llanes"
2022-11-10 13:27:09,109 [ajp-nio-8889-exec-11 | u:julien.llanes | u:julien.llanes] INFO  root  - State of job "Generate Variant Documents" changed to ACTIVATING
2022-11-10 13:27:09,109 [ajp-nio-8889-exec-11 | u:julien.llanes | u:julien.llanes] INFO  root  - State of job "Generate Variant Documents" changed to WAITING
2022-11-10 13:27:09,124 [Worker-25: Generate Variant Documents | u:julien.llanes] INFO  root  - State of job "Generate Variant Documents" changed to RUNNING
2022-11-10 13:27:09,140 [Worker-25: Generate Variant Documents | u:julien.llanes | job: polarion.jobs.variant_management] INFO  root  - Generating Variant specifications for document: Master Specifications / Feature User and Functional Requirements Specification from project ADEPT Requirements
2022-11-10 13:27:09,156 [Worker-25: Generate Variant Documents | u:julien.llanes] INFO  root  - State of job "Generate Variant Documents" changed to FINISHED
2022-11-10 13:27:09,156 [Worker-25: Generate Variant Documents | u:julien.llanes] INFO  root  - Status of job "Generate Variant Documents" is FAILED:
Pure Variants server cannot be found.
Please contact your administrator.
com.polarion.core.util.exceptions.UserFriendlyRuntimeException: Pure Variants server cannot be found.
Please contact your administrator.
    at com.polarion.purevariants.pv.Variant.loadPureVariantsProject(Variant.java:93)
    at com.polarion.purevariants.pv.Variant.<init>(Variant.java:66)
    at com.polarion.purevariants.VariantManagementProvider.loadVariant(VariantManagementProvider.java:147)
    at com.polarion.purevariants.VariantManagementProvider.generateSpecificationsForVariant(VariantManagementProvider.java:121)
    at com.polarion.alm.tracker.internal.variantmanagement.VariantManagementService.generateSpecificationsForVariant(VariantManagementService.java:72)
    at $IVariantManagementService_1844f4ec800.generateSpecificationsForVariant($IVariantManagementService_1844f4ec800.java)
    at com.polarion.alm.tracker.internal.variantmanagement.VariantManagementJob$VariantManagementJobUnit$1.runWEx(VariantManagementJob.java:106)
    at com.polarion.alm.tracker.internal.variantmanagement.VariantManagementJob$VariantManagementJobUnit$1.runWEx(VariantManagementJob.java:1)
    at com.polarion.core.util.RunnableWEx.runWRet(RunnableWEx.java:61)
    at com.polarion.platform.TransactionExecuter.execute(TransactionExecuter.java:162)
    at com.polarion.alm.tracker.internal.variantmanagement.VariantManagementJob$VariantManagementJobUnit.runInternal(VariantManagementJob.java:100)
    at com.polarion.platform.jobs.spi.AbstractJobUnit.run(AbstractJobUnit.java:194)
    at com.polarion.platform.jobs.internal.eclipse.WrappedEclipseRootJob$2$1.runWEx(WrappedEclipseRootJob.java:208)
    at com.polarion.platform.jobs.internal.eclipse.WrappedEclipseRootJob$2$1.runWEx(WrappedEclipseRootJob.java:1)
    at com.polarion.core.util.RunnableWEx.runWRet(RunnableWEx.java:61)
    at com.polarion.platform.persistence.internal.JobContextService.doInContext(JobContextService.java:24)
    at com.polarion.platform.persistence.internal.JobContextService.doInContext(JobContextService.java:1)
    at com.polarion.platform.jobs.internal.eclipse.WrappedEclipseRootJob$2.run(WrappedEclipseRootJob.java:200)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:484)
    at com.polarion.platform.internal.security.SubjectNDC.doAsPrivileged(SubjectNDC.java:80)
    at com.polarion.platform.jobs.internal.eclipse.WrappedEclipseRootJob.runJob(WrappedEclipseRootJob.java:190)
    at com.polarion.platform.jobs.internal.eclipse.WrappedEclipseRootJob.runJobs(WrappedEclipseRootJob.java:167)
    at com.polarion.platform.jobs.internal.eclipse.WrappedEclipseRootJob.run(WrappedEclipseRootJob.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:60)
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone searching for this in the future, we had a server migration a few months ago, and the variant server wasn't reinstalled.
Although all the other features worked (like the Variant model, restrictions, etc).
Installed the correct variant server (inside the Pure Variant folder), initialised the variant server (via the Polarion admin page, under Variants), and now it's working ok.